# Get list of files in Library folder with sandbox in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to get list of files in Library folder in cocoa, i use this code and NSHomeDrirectory() function without sandboxing and work well.

```
TempArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:FolderURL]
```

but when I checked sandbox is code not work, Is it any entitlements should i add? or what code can replace?

Comment: I don't think you can access either `~/Library` or `/Library` without the user explicitly allowing you access via `NSOpenPanel`.  Read the sandbox guides at Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried if this will get all the files but it should since you can save and read files from the library.

```
NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *libraryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:libraryPath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add below entitlement you can access ~/Library or /Library folders

```
  com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write: /Library/
```

But after this you will get reply from apple is

2.31:Apps that are not sandboxed appropriately may be rejected
I didn't get answer of this. If anyone knows please post here.